# 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - but id of user exist

Tags: sql, laravel, auto-increment

I have three table ; `users` , `products` and `transactions`
the id fields is auto increment in laravel.

products :

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
        $table->integer('price')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

transactions :

```
Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id()->from('1000');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->integer('code')->nullable();
        $table->string('token')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('amount');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

users :

```
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('phone');
        $table->timestamp('last_seen')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

when I insert new row on `products` or `transactions` it give me this error :

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sabbabecom_DB`.`products`, CONSTRAINT` products_user_id_foreign `FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES` users `(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)`

insert into `products` (`user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, 2022-06-25 09:38:52, 2022-06-25 09:38:52)

or :

insert into `transactions` (`user_id`, `amount`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, 56000,  2022-06-25 09:50:14, 2022-06-25 09:50:14)

But in the users table , a user with id `2` is exist !!!

what is wrong in my database?

thanks